# javascript linking

Tags: javascript, html

I'm going to build a rather complicated application in html5 with some heavy javascripting.
In this I need to make some objects which can be pass around. But since there is no like @import foobar.js.

Then I assume that if my html page loads the scripts, then all the scripts can access eachother?

I read [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file) that ajax somehow is able to load a .js file from within another .js file. But i dont think this is what I need?

Can go more into details if needed, thanks in advance.

Comment: haven't you heard about <script src="..."></script> ?
all your .js files can acces eachother ...

Comment: Can't see why a valid question, even though it might be "stupid" and had no other questions like this on the site, should get -1. @micnic if it was u... jezz what an attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the module pattern:
http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth/

This describes alternatives for creating modular code in javascript, how you can protect your code and share APIs and data among them.

You should also consider using and AMD. [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) is quite popular, but I tend to prefer [head.js](http://headjs.com) for this. Keep in mind that these put some requirements on how you structur your code in files, and personally, I don't think it's worth it, compared to a concatenated and minified file included in the bottom of the page.

Comment: You're welcome. The article is a classic :) I added a section about AMDs, which should be considered regarding client side architecture.

Answer (score 2):

In our projects, we do the following: Suppose you're going to call your project Foo, and have a module called Bar in it,

Then what we do is declare a file called Foo.js that just defines an equivalent to a Foo namespace:

```
Foo = (function(){
    return {
        };
})();
```

Then we create a file called Foo.Bar.js that contains the code for the Bar module:

```
Foo.Bar = (function(){
    // var declarations here that should be invisible outside Foo.Bar
var p, q;   
    return {            
        fun1 : function(a, b){
            // Code for fun1 here
        },      
        fun2 : function(c) {
            // Code for fun2 here
        }            
    } // return 
})();
```

Note that how it is a function that executes immediately, and returns an object that gets assigned to `Foo.Bar`. Any local variables, like `p` and `q` are available to `fun1` and `fun2` because they're in a closure, but they are invisible outside of `Foo.Bar`

The functions in Foo.Bar can be constructors for objects and so on.

Now in your HTML you simple include both files like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Foo.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="Foo.Bar.js"></script>
```

The result will be that you can call `Foo.Bar`'s functions in the JavaScript of your main HTML file without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I assume that if my html page loads the scripts, then all the scripts can access eachother?

Yes.